# All minimum cuts in flow network

Tags: graphs, network-flow

I'm trying to prove that for a flow network, maximum flow `f`, and each minimum cut `S` that `f(S)=c(S)`.

Max flow min cut promises that there exists a cut where `f(S)=c(S)`; I want to prove that given multiple minimal `s-t` cuts `Si`, that `c(S1)=f(S1)=c(S2)=f(S2)...`,  meaning all outgoing edges of all minimal cuts are fully saturated.

It seems very intuitive to me but I can't seem to get it.

I want to say that the flow for any `s-t` cut is equal to the flow going into `t`.  How can I prove that?

I'm guessing that I need to rely on the fact that for each vertex the incoming flow equals the outgoing flow but I don't really see how.

Comment: "Max flow min cut promises that there exists a cut where f(S)=c(S)" -- max-flow-min-cut is *exactly* your claim.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!